# Upstairs wall studs sitting on top of subflooring that needs to be removed

Tags: flooring, subfloor, remodeling, old-house, renovation

I am currently renovating the entire second floor of my 1920's home and have run into an issue. The subflooring is currently unleveled and had intentions of pulling up the subflooring, adding a sister joist along the existing joist to relevel the floors and then laying back the original flooring. Upon pulling up some of the flooring we realized that the wall studs are resting on the flooring instead of the studs going through the flooring and being secured to the joist. Another dilemma is that the walls are off centered from the floor joist creating no support for the studs if the flooring is removed. I am currently unsure of what the next step should be or if there needs to be another route taken for this task.

Comment: Go through the ceiling instead.

Comment: Are you saying that the 2nd floor walls, which probably also support the roof to some degree, are resting on floor sheet in random unsupported places, rather than on structural members? Could it be that these are "false walls" that were built later, on the inside of the original structure?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Unless this is a nonstructural wall (as mentioned above), the part of the subfloor under the wall is now part of the building structure.  If you want to remove subflooring *not* under the wall you'll have to cut it and leave the part under the wall.

Comment: To ask the question from @JimmyFix-it another way: is there no bottom plate to the stud wall? If that’s the case, add one and all your issues will go away.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "going through the ceiling "@popham.

Comment: This is basically where I am at right now @Huesmann. I will have to leave the floor that is currently under the walls. The floor joist are 2x6" that are 24" spacing spanning 14' btw.

Comment: I would like to run a base plate @Aloysius Defenestrate, but unsure if it will make a difference when the studs are running paralle with the joist and not sitting directly on them.

Comment: You can install the joists from below instead of from above without removing any flooring. Remove the ceiling below instead. You could do a hybrid, installing a joist below your wall from below so that you can then cut the floor and proceed from above. You could sneak chunks of 2x4 into the ceiling from below and use screw jacks or similar to hold the wall in place temporarily.

Comment: You could frame a truss on the face of the wall to transfer all of the wall's interior weight to the ends of the wall. (Assuming that there's something substantial to support both ends of the truss.)

Comment: Sorry, didn’t get that the wall ran parallel to the joists and fell between. In that case, block across the joists and add the plate.

Comment: And it feels like we might have something like a gambrel roof and a non-bearing wall here. Can you describe the roof and any substantial supporting members (beams, posts)?

Comment: @Evan once you've cut the subfloor you'll probably want to run blocking between the joists, adjacent to the bottom plate, to provide support for the replacement subfloor.